# Is $\operatorname{Rep}(G,\operatorname{SL}_2)$ representable by an algebraic space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks, algebraic-spaces

Let $G$ be a finite group. Consider the category of rigid analytic spaces over $\operatorname{Spf}\mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $\operatorname{Rep}(G, \operatorname{SL}_2)$ be the fibred category above it, with fibre $\operatorname{Rep}(G, \operatorname{SL}_2(U))$ above $U$ of the groupoid of isomorphism classes of representations $G\longrightarrow \operatorname{SL}_2(U)$ above it.

$\operatorname{Rep}(G,\operatorname{SL}_2)$ is a fibred category with descent, making it a stack. My question is if this stack is in fact an algebraic space, if this makes sense.

Comment: Can't such a representation have nontrivial automorphisms? (Take a direct sum of two irreducible one dimensional reps).  So probably to get an algebraic space you need to rigidify more / exclude these.

Comment: In the world of schemes over a field $K$ the space $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{SL_2})$ of homomorphisms $\rho:G \to \operatorname{SL_2}$ is representable by a scheme of finite type. [Choose generators $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, then $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{SL_2})$ can be realised as a closed subspace of $\operatorname{SL_2}^n$ cut out by the relations.] If the order of $G$ is invertible in $K$, then this is in fact a disjoint union of (open and closed) $\operatorname{SL_2}$-orbits...

Comment: ... And the set of orbits is in bijection with the set of isomorphism classes of $\rho:G \to \operatorname{SL}_2(\overline{K})$ over an algebraic closure of $K$. Now consider the finite etale $K$-scheme $\pi_0(\operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{SL_2}))$. Under the assumption that the order of $G$ is invertible in $K$, this should represent the (etale) sheafification(!) of the presheaf $U \mapsto \{\text{isomorphism classes of } \rho:G \to \operatorname{SL}_2(U)\}$. I suspect something similar should be true in the case of rigid analytic spaces.

Comment: The stack given by $U \mapsto \{\text{groupoid of } \rho:G \to \operatorname{SL}_2(U)\}$ is an algebraic stack, which is the (stack) quotient of $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{SL_2})$ by the natural conjugation action of $\operatorname{SL}_2$. If the order of $G$ is invertible in $K$, then this is a disjoint union of classifying stacks, corresponding to the stabilisers of the $\operatorname{SL}_2$-orbits in $\operatorname{Hom}(G,\operatorname{SL_2})$. See Appendix A1 and A2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.06708.pdf for more details.

Comment: The name of @PolvanHoften's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436583/is-operatornamerepg-operatornamesl-2-representable-by-an-algebraic-spa#comment1126948_436583):  [Dat, Helm, Kurinczuk, and Moss - Moduli of Langlands Parameters](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06708)